# Using promise .then return promise and wrap previous response

Tags: node.js, promise

As I understand, `promise.then` returns a new promise. But how to return this promise with a value. Here is my sample code

```
function sleep(input, timeout) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve(input), timeout)});
}

async function main() {
  sleep(['a','b'],1000)
  .then(([first, second]) => {
    console.log(first)
    console.log(second);
    return [first+'t', second];
  });
}
main()
.then(res => {
  console.log(res);
})
```

The log output

```
a
b
undefined
```

Expected

```
a
b
['at', 'b']
```

Comment: you need to return the sleep from main `main(){return sleep...}`

Comment: Thanks Todd, works for me. Could give me more explanation.

Comment: Functions return `undefined` in JS without a `return` statement. Your main function thus sent `undefined` to the `then` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `console.log(res)` you want to print the value returned by `sleep.then(...)` inside the `main()` function. However, that function is not returning that value. In fact, it isn't returning anything, so `res` is `undefined`.

Inside `main()`, you should return `sleep.then(...)`. That way, `res` will be the value which is returned by that promise.

```js
function sleep(input, timeout) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve(input), timeout)});
}

async function main() {
  return sleep(['a','b'],1000)
  .then(([first, second]) => {
    console.log(first)
    console.log(second);
    return [first+'t', second];
  });
}
main()
.then(res => {
  console.log(res);
})
```